# Unable to connect to SQL Server locally

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am getting the following exception when I am trying to connect to a web service

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file DatabaseName.mdb failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

The connection string I am using is:

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|WS_Assignment.mdb;uid=Admin;pwd=" 
providerName="System.Data.OleDb"
```

I am trying to access SQL Server on local system.

I have gone through a lot of articles and followed all the different methods. But I got no solution.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: `.mdb` is MS **Access** - **not** SQL Server ....

Comment: I have a ms access database. how do i make it into a .mdf database to access on SQL server?

Comment: Create your SQL Server database (in e.g. Management Studio), and then use e.g. SQL Server Integration Services (the "Data Import" wizard) to import your Access data into SQL Server

Comment: Thanks marc_s
I think what you pointed out was helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Before Question was EDITED:**

are you deploying on a web server , instead of your localhost. If thats the case you need to publish the sql script in Server DB as servers dont allow attachDB file in your deployment and if thats the case then your problem is solved.

**After Update**
you can always try with fullpath and yes you need OLEDB call not sql make sure thats not the case with your .cs code

Correction in your question:

> i am trying to access SQL server On local system

:
i dont see how you can do that with .mdb file; even if thats not the case make sure sql services are running properly in your system go to->start button->program files->microsoft sql server yourversion-> configuration manager-> check running services.

Answer (score 0):

In your `Solution Explorer`, click on `"Show All Files".` then go to your `App_Data` folder and delete `WS_assignment.mdb` and then run your application.

Also, your provider is  wrong

```
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" is the right one.
```

Secondly, your database name should end in `.mdf` or `.sdf` for SQL Server.

So, your connection string will become:

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectionStringName"
     connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|WS_Assignment.sdf"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Also: for `.sdf` (= SQL Server Compact) you will need to use a different `providerName=....` value! The one you're giving is only for the *full* SQL Server version (**not** for SQL Server CE)

Answer (score 0):

Check this.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/5ybdbtte%28v=vs.71%29.aspx
using Access requires **System.Data.OleDb** library